# Чи справдї гіперкорекція: хрін → хрону

Tags: фонетика

Декотрі джерела, в тому числї [вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC), наводять таке:

> З часом ця система ставала дедалі незрозумілішою, тому первісну фонетичну мотивацію переходу [і] в [о], [е] нині дещо втрачено, через що виникли гіперкорекційні форми типу *хрін*-*хрону* (прасл. **xrěnъ*).

Чи тут міг зіграти фактор досить [порширеного явишча](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wxDKI3BEbuMJ:https://library.udpu.edu.ua/library_files/filologichniy-chacopys/2019/1/19.pdf&cd=5&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua&lr=-lang_ru) як *ствердїння **р***, тобто в записах зник їть і почало відмінювати ся як звичне *і*. В більшостї випадків *рѣ* не маїть зміни: *грїх – грїха*, *рїка – рїки*, тому можу згадати лише *рїч* і похідні як *речї – доречний*, але брати ся за це слово не дуже благородна справа, бо корїнь [мінливий:](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87#10538) *пророк*, *наврочити* ітд. І шукати незручно: [*дорочний*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22) може стосувати *речі* і *року*, [*рочення*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22) часто є частиною гинших слів як *відстрочення*, *скорочення*, *осирочення*, *запаморочення* ітд; також при оціфровання *е* часом можить розпізнавати ся як *о*, що недивно, бо за виглядом досить однакові, особливо коли фарба потїкла. Звісно, вжитки *потрїбні* декотрі трапяють ся, як і [*до рочі*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&newwindow=1&tbs=lr%3A-lang_1ru&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%96%22&nfpr=1), але проаналізовати такі слова складно.

Поки писав абзац вишче, попали ся [*потрїб*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B1), шчо є книжним словом, шчо теж можить бути фактором, і *корїнь*, котрого вже легше шукати за [*короневий*](//google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&newwindow=1), [*коронева*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%22), де вжитку теж мало, але чомусь зустрїчаїть ся і на осїдках з *edu.ua* і *gov.ua*: [*короневий каталог*](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:s7UlZ1OfOokJ:https://essuir.sumdu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/73581/1/Kozak._bachelor_thesis.pdf&cd=22&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua), [*короневий канал*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jdSlOvTv65IJ:moodle.bsmu.edu.ua/file.php/733/Ortopedichna_stomatolog_2014_baza.rtf&cd=21&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua), [*коронева губка*](//kyivlis.gov.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/PZPSS-DP-Vyshhedubechanskyj-lisgosp-25.06.2019..pdf).

Comment: Я так розумію, мова про те, що мова про те, що _і_ зазвичай переходить в _о_, коли стоїть на місці праслов'янського _o_ (дім — вдома (псл. *domъ), дріб — дробовий (псл. *drobь), рід — роду (псл. *rodъ) тощо), а не коли стоїть на місці праслов'янського _ě_, тобто фактично ѣ (грілка — гріти (псл. *grěti), гріх — гріха (псл. *grěxъ), кріпкий — кріпити (псл. *krěpъkъ), прілка — пріти (псл. *prěti), рідкий — рідина (псл. *rědъkъ), річка — ріка (псл. rěka) тощо). Звісно, є винятки (напр.: псл. *krъtъ мало б бути крот — крота (але кріт); псл. *xrěnъ мало б бути хрін — хріна (але хрона)).

Comment: P.S.: А посилання на Google Cache (замість прямих посилань, наприклад могло б бути: [1](https://library.udpu.edu.ua/library_files/filologichniy-chacopys/2019/1/19.pdf), [2](https://essuir.sumdu.edu.ua/bitstream-download/123456789/73581/1/Kozak._bachelor_thesis.pdf), [3](https://kyivlis.gov.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/PZPSS-DP-Vyshhedubechanskyj-lisgosp-25.06.2019..pdf)) навмисне чи випадково?

Comment: @Sasha, Śćosj take, tipa *P¹ěPъ*, de *P¹* — stverdêlıj **p**rıholosnıj, śćo moźıtj povodıtı sja jak *PoPъ*. Pro *PъPъ* і *PьPъ* ne pıtav, ale jakśćo tam podôbni javıśća ćerez *ě* — moźıte dopovnıtı vêdpovêdj, zaraz moźu zhadatı lıśe *ledъ*, śćo v suć. ukr. movê stalo jak [*lěd*](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/Галицкіи_приповѣдки_и_загадки/Приповѣдки/Р), ale [*bez*] *ljodu* navêtj bez stverdênnja *l*.

Śćodo *Google Cache* — naumısno.

Comment: А навіщо, якщо не секрет, Google Cache? PъPъ я спробував навести лише як приклад, що не завжди закони «*ě → і», «*o → і/о», «*ъ → о» втілюються. (Як гадаєте, чи варто оформити коментар як відповідь, чи воно не сильно помічне?)